# Google App engine running slow

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

I'm having problems deploying an app to App Engine. Is there anything I have to configure to allow app engine apps to run smoothly?

I've uploaded this example: https://github.com/akshayrangnekar/gaemavenjerseyguice

It works correctly when I run it at localhost, but when I upload it... It works really bad.

And it runs so slow... Do I have to enable billing or something?

Thanks!

Comment: The more often you use it the faster it gets. Like if no one is hitting the server for a while (err maybe 15 min?), instances get turned off and to fire them up again takes time.

Answer (score 2):

It could seem slow because App Engine can scale up and down from zero. The very first request will run slower than subsequent requests after an instance is up. If your site is getting pretty regular traffic you shouldn't be seeing slow responses.

Also, you can check out [Cloud Trace in the Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/traces/overview) if you need to see what parts of your requests are taking the longest and then have some information on how to tackle the problem if it isn't related to the first instance starting up.

Answer (score -1):

Increase CPU and memory it may help, configure the ressource part of your yaml file.